# ci : google indexing address with index.php but there is no link with index.php in the site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, seo, codeigniter-url

i have a website written by codeigniter , i've removed index.php from address via htaccess

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

my base_url() will output site domain without index.php as well 
so all my links in the site are without index.php ie :

```
www.site.com/news/add
www.site.com/faq
www.site.com/offers/archive
```

so here is the problem :
i've noticed google has indexed lots of addresses from my site with index php as well 
for example i have this address in my site :

```
www.site.com/offer/map
```

but google only have

```
www.shadyab.com/index.php/offer/map
```

indexed not the first one !

where is google getting these links ?

here is my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['cp'] = 'cp/admin';
$route['404.php']      = "404.php";
$route["page/(:any)"]   = "page/title/$1";
$route["offers/(:any)"] = "offer/get/$1";
$route["category/(:any)"] = "offer/open/0/$1";
$route["rss"] = "news/rssOffers";
$route['sitemap\.xml'] = "offer/sitemap";
```

my htaccess

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on



#forcing www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# redirecting addresses with index.php to address without it
# (i've added this just yesterday it's not related to my problem )
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [L,R]

#adding inddex.php internally 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 



</IfModule>


order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Comment: from your config.php set $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: are you missing a rewriterule?

Comment: related -- if google results are important then setting up google webmaster tools for the website will help you http://www.google.com/webmasters/

Comment: @cartalot i'm just the programmer  , we have a seo guy how i think has already created a account and he's the one who said we have this problem

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 i've added my htaccess at the end ,  there just a little part which is enforcing www

Comment: max - if the website is registered with google webmaster tools then you can disallow specific google results like this. the best would be if you can get access to the account, the tools are easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your website is redirecting `index.php` but it is sending a `302` redirect which is a [temporary redirect](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3).  What you want to do is use a `301` [Moved Permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2).

Using the `301`, google will be notified that the old URL is no longer valid and update their index with the new url.

[image: Change 302]

Add this rule to your `.htaccess`

`RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: thanx i,ve posted my full htaccess pleas take a look , so i did as you said , first i have a code (in htacc) which is redirecting address with index.php to address without it  (second part in htacc ) bot now it giving me error `The page isn't redirecting properly` here is the reason : now if i remove this redirecting code completely  all my address will be redirected to an address with index.php ! like if i try `a.com/b` it will redirect to `a.com/index.php/b` and all i did is adding `[R=301,L]` to my rule